# Is there a term for the other 2 months in a quarter?

Tags: time

The organization I work for has monthly volunteer opportunities, and quarterly volunteer opportunities. The trouble comes when someone serves quarterly (say, the 1st Monday of each quarter) and we need to fill the other 2 first Mondays of the months in that quarter. Is there a term for that time frame?

Comment: Even if there was such a word, I doubt it would be meaningful for any potential volunteers. Better just to specify the dates.  I wouldn't bend over backwards, linguistically or otherwise, for someone who's only volunteering 4 days a year.

Comment: The new volunteers are also serving quarterly (four times a year), just not in the first Monday of each quarter. There isn't a specific term for months 2, 5, 8 and 11 -- just as "quarterly" doesn't specify months 1, 4, 7 and 10.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. @AndrewLeach that's the rub - there are a number of volunteers who pick up both of those other 1st Mondays, so they are actually serving months 2 & 3, 5 & 6, 7 & 8, etc. That's why I was wondering about a term for each of those sets of months. In any case, thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you know exactly which months you're short of volunteers. Why not simply ask for volunteers for those months instead of devising a formula?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some suggestions for ways to phrase different combinations of days in a calendar quarter.

If someone works the first two Mondays of a quarter, the second two Mondays are available for *Second-Half Quarterly Volunteers*. The opposite: *First-Half Quarterly Volunteers*. If every other Monday (1 & 3, 5 & 7, etc.) is reserved, the *Alternating Even Mondays* are available for quarterly volunteers; the same could be said for *Alternating Odd Monday Volunteers*. If the first and last Mondays are booked, *Middle Monday Volunteers* are needed; the opposite could be *First/Last Monday Volunteers*. If a random selection of Mondays have already been reserved, the *difference of Mondays* are available for quarterly volunteers.